# What exactly is the default value for "c" and "r" parameters in Zebra's B7 command?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I'm trying to understand Zebra's B7 command.
The format is `^B7o,h,s,c,r,t`

I understand what each parameter is but I don't understand the default values of "c" and "r".

Given this example `^B7N,10,5,14` "c"=14 and "r" is defaulted. But to what? The description in the ZPLII programming guide states "1 : 2 (row-to-column aspect ratio)".

I don't understand it. What does it mean? What is the actual value for "r" in the above example?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

c is the number of columns, r is the number of rows.

c*r must be <=928.

r=2*c by default.